# Python PIL.ExifTags - Not sure what it is all about

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am reading through some code I found on [GitHub](https://gist.github.com/erans/983821)(see code extract below) relating to getting the Latitude and Longitude from EXIF using PIL. I can mostly follow what is happening except for TAGS.get(tags,tags). When I review the [Pillow reference material](https://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/ExifTags.html?highlight=class%20pil.exiftags.gpstag#PIL.ExifTags.PIL.ExifTags.GPSTAGS), it gives an example, but not enough for me to know what the code is pulling in or why the code has two "tag" varibles show eg (tags,tag). If someone could shed some light on the issue or provide a link to more detailed reference material, it would greatly be appreciated.

```python
def get_exif_data(image):
    """Returns a dictionary from the exif data of an PIL Image item. Also converts the GPS Tags"""
    exif_data = {}
    info = image._getexif()
    if info:
        for tag, value in info.items():
            decoded = TAGS.get(tag, tag)
            if decoded == "GPSInfo":
                gps_data = {}
                for t in value:
                    sub_decoded = GPSTAGS.get(t, t)
                    gps_data[sub_decoded] = value[t]

                exif_data[decoded] = gps_data
            else:
                exif_data[decoded] = value
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ExifTags.TAGS` is a dictionary.  Here's the whole dictionary:
https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/master/src/PIL/ExifTags.py

As such, you can get the value for a given key by using `TAGS.get(key)`.
If that key does not exist, you can have it return to you a default value by passing in a second argument `TAGS.get(key, val)`

Source:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_get.htm

> get(key[, default]) Return the value for key if key is in the
>   dictionary, else default. If default is not given, it defaults to
>   None, so that this method never raises a KeyError.

Source: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get

Answer (score 0):

i just run your code . you have to import another moudle like this:***from PIL.ExifTags import GPSTAGS***. and then it will not run error.